# Has anyone successfully uninstalled multiversion/workspace?

Tags: 8

I can't edit nodes with paragraphs because what appears to be an incompatibility with mutliversion. I need paragraphs more so have tried to remove multiversion, this means removing workspace, but as soon as I remove workspace entities:

> There is content for the entity type: Workspace. Remove workspace entities (admin/modules/uninstall/entity/workspace).

My site dies…

`Error: Call to a member function id() on null in /web/modules/contrib/workspace/src/EntityAccess.php on line 104`

I've run through the uninstall every way I can think of without any success… Any guidance would be most appreciated!